# How to retain icon dimensions in a responsive design? Without using pixels

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, icons, size

First of all, I just wanted to say this page is for a Web Design course.

I have icons for social media in a responsive page I'm building, and I've applied a `max-width:3%` to all of them to reduce their original size, as they were too big before. Now, as I reduce the size of the window, I would like the icons stay responsive while retaining their new size. However, the icons scale as well, making them appear too small. I know I could use pixels to define a fixed size, but one of the objectives of this exercise is to *not* set image values in pixels (just allowed for padding values).

Is there a way to achieve this?

My html codes

```
<div id="footwrap">     
        <footer>

            <div id="footh3">
                <h3 class="h3">Follow me on social media:</h3>
            </div>

            <div id="footlink">
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">                  
                    <img src="images/facebook-icon.svg" alt="Facebook">             
                </a>

                <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank">                     
                    <img src="images/instagram-icon.svg" alt="Instagram">               
                </a>

                <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">                       
                    <img src="images/youtube-icon.svg" alt="YouTube">               
                </a>

                <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank">                       
                    <img src="images/twitter-icon.svg" alt="Twitter">               
                </a>
            </di>

        </footer>
</div>
```

My CSS style:

```
#footwrap {
clear: both;
padding: 2%;
}

footer {
position: relative;
clear: both;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
height: 8em;
margin-top: 12%;
}

#footh3 {
display: inline-block;
}

footer h3 {
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-size: 1.17em;
margin-bottom: 2em;
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
font-weight: bold;
}

#footlink {
display: inline-block;
}

footer a {
text-decoration: none;
}

footer img {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 3%;
height: auto;   
margin-left: 1.5%;
margin-right: 10px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The desired outcome would be how the icons in the top right corner of this page react when the web browser window is reduced: http://www.omganeshaya.com/

Comment: So what would be the desired outcome?

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for the late reply. I'll try what you suggested and I've also added a more info about what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to adjust to a higher percentage as the page gets smaller. see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/622r62mp/

For more information about media queries you can reference this site https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

CSS example

```
img{max-width:3%}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  img{max-width:9%}
}
@media (max-width: 600px){
  img{max-width:15%}
}
```

Comment: I think this is as good as you are going to get without using any px widths at all.